# Сохранение чисел с плавающей точкой в C

Tags: c

```
double d;
float f;
```

1) `d = 1e16 + 1;` (d = 10000000000000000)
Почему "теряется" еденица, как это можно объяснить?

2)

```
f = 10000 * 100000;
f += 1;
f -= 4 * 250000000;
```

(f = 0) Снова теряется единица, как можно объяснить

3) `f = 10000 * 100000 + 1 - 4 * 250000000;` тоже самое, но тут уже не теряется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Плавающие типы не гарантируют точного представления всех значений в пределах своего диапазона. Ваша "потерянная 1" - это и есть пример неточности плавающего типа.
2. "Потеря 1" происходит на этапе `f += 1;` по той же причине, что и в пункте 1.
3. Все операнды в выражении `10000 * 100000 + 1 - 4 * 250000000` - целочисленные, т.е. вычисление этого выражения ведется в рамках *целого* знакового типа. Целочисленные типы всегда точно представляют значения в рамках своего диапазона, про каковой причине результат этого выражения получается точным.

Comment: Про 3 понял, а вот в первом и соответсвенно втором хочу разобраться подробнее. Где конкретно теряется точность? Из-за порядка, мантиссы?

Comment: Во втором в самом коде переменная называется просто "f", тут заменил для того что-бы было однозначно понятно какого она типа

Comment: @Danil Lyamkin: Из-за мантиссы, разумеется. Ширины мантиссы недостаточно - младшие разряды теряются.